# Which power converter topology has higher benefit of EMI/EMC?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, led-driver, electromagnetic

Which power converter topology can be best suited for EMC compliance for small power converter to be used in LED lighting products. In my context I'm using a 5W non-isolated AC-DC converter which is not complying as per EN-55015 standard. 
Any suggestion to use isolated Flpyback topology for the same application if this can yield better EMI performance ove non-isolated buck.

Comment: What do you mean by "higher benefit"? Are you asking what the best type is EMC-wise?

Comment: Is it possible to ground a non-isolated supply like flyback or capacitive dropper?